# fix warning: the jks keystore uses a proprietary format. it is recommended to migrate to pkcs12

Tags: android-studio

I wanted to generate my app but when I created a keystore I got this error
how can i fix it
i do not have any knowledge about it
please send a video if it is possible

warning: the jks keystore uses a proprietary format. it is recommended to migrate to pkcs12

Comment: I'm also getting this warning when trying to run Xamarin.UITests and I'm interested in the solution